# How to Make a jQuery Table Cell(td) clickable to Run a Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, html-table

I am currently passing the button class to a function when the button is clicked.
I want to switch from using buttons to using the td/cells in a jQuery table.
So when I click on the image in the cell, it runs the function, passing its class value to it.
There are 4 rows in the table, each row will pass a different class value.
Each cell/td in a row will pass exactly the same class value to the function (for now).

Someone helped me with this using buttons and now I need to do the same with the cells

For example, one button is set as below:

```
<input type="button" class="clear" style="width:110px;" onclick="return SetShift(this.className)" value="Clear" />
```

I was provided with an example on how to do this with a table but I am really struggling to fit this in with my code.

The example is:

```
<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)">Clear</td>
```

I do not need the button to have a value itself as I am using images, but this is not the problem.

Below is the table code (which is created in an external jQuery file), as it currently is:

```
var $table = $('<table>');
$table.append()

//tbody
var $tbody = $table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');

// add row
$tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
.append("<th>Clear</th>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>");

// add another row
$tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
.append("<th>Earlies</th>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>");

// add another row
$tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
.append("<th>Lates</th>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>");

// add another row
$tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
.append("<th>Double</th>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>")
.append("<td></td>");

// add table to dom
$table.appendTo('#dynamicTable');
```

I have tried the below:

```
.append(<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>);
```

But this gives the following error on page load:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
.append("<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>");
.append(""<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>"");
```

But these gives the following error on page load:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

And with my limited knowledge I have tried changing other various syntax with equally bad results.
I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.append('<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>')
```

and if there is anything like this on your code,

```
.append("<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>");
.append(""<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>"");
```

change this to

```
.append('<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>')
.append('<td class="clear" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>')
```

**#update**

You are appending the td like `append().append().append()`......etc. So you don't close that after each line.

Comment: Thanks very much but I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Actually please let me check that again.

Comment: Ok. You have to make changes for everything that uses onclick

Comment: Should I be using the closing ; on each line or just the last line?

Comment: Oh sorry. No you shouldn't. Because you are using append like chain. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks, the table loads now and is clickable (which is more than I could manage) but I get the error: (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: setShift is not defined at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick ((index):1)  -  Maybe this is because it is not defined in the external jQuery file?

Comment: Yes. That's because you haven't defined the `onClick` function in js file

Comment: I am just googling how to define the onClick function in the js file.

Comment: Could you mark it as answer, if the question you addressed is solved ?

Comment: You can define your onclick function in js file just like any other function.

Comment: Thanks. This was my first time to create an external js. So not sure how to define the function at all. I have copied it in from the html file but am still getting the same error. Probably have it in the wrong place so am trying different variations until I figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198072/discussion-between-melvin-and-flakie).

Comment: Thank you for all your help. As the links in the table are now working and attempting to run the function I will mark the question as answered. I will try to resolve the problem I have with my external js file and the function not being available. I will ask a new question if I am unable to resolve by myself but want to give it a good go first.

Comment: @flakie Ok sure. Feel free to ask